# Python: Call a variable from another function within a class in pygame

Tags: python

I am coding this code with pygame with python but for some reason, its say there isn't `self.tiles()` .

```
import pygame
from tile import Tile

class Level:
    def __init__(self,level_data,surface):
        self.display_surface = surface
        self.setup_level = (level_data)

    def setup_level(self,layout):
        self.tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for row in layout:
            print(row)

    def run(self):
        self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)
```

For more information, I got this code from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWN8GcmJ-jA&list=PL8ui5HK3oSiGXM2Pc2DahNu1xXBf7WQh-&index=2).

Comment: `self.tiles` only exists if you have executed `setup_level()` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Level.setup_level method isn't called before your code attempts to access the tiles.
Also, self.tiles is defined as a variable, not a function - which you are trying to call, only functions are callable - you do that by writing function name followed by brackets, like this

```
function()
```

Comment: There are many objects which are 'callable', not just functions.

Comment: I don't get it. can you put that into the code

Comment: @nub can you paste the exact error code?

Comment: line 15, in run
    self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)
AttributeError: 'Level' object has no attribute 'tiles'

Comment: In the code snippet you provided there's no 'draw' method. Bug might lie there

Comment: I don't think so. Here is the code snippet  https://github.com/tushortz/vscode-Pygame-Snippets/blob/master/snippets/pygame.json